# Magento 1.9.x - Blocks not being displayed from local module

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, product-view, custom-block

I am creating a module to add some extra call to action buttons.
I cannot get an output to display.   I believe I am getting either the naming conventions or the file location (or both) wrong.

It may also be the way I am trying to insert the block. I dont want to modify the phtml files if I can avoid it.

As you can see from my files, I am trying a number of ways to get the *anything* to be output - with no luck.

The aim is to be able to add additional CTA buttons after Add to Cart - such as 'Request Samples'

File structure:

```
app
    Code
        local
            CompanyName
                CtaAttributes
                    Block -> CtaButtons.php
                    etc -> config.xml
    design
        frontend
            base
                default
                    layout->ctabuttons.xml
                    template
                        ctaattributes
                            catelog
                               product ->ctabuttons.phtml
```

config.xml

```
<config>

    ... includes Module and Resource

    <global>
      <blocks>
        <ctaattributes>
            <class>CompanyName_CtaAttributes_Block</class>
        </ctaattributes>
      </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

CtaButtons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>    
        <reference name="content">

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.addtocart" before="addtocart" template="ctaattributes/catalog/product/ctabuttons.phtml"/>
                <action method="append">
                        <block>ctabuttons</block>
                </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="core-text"><action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<div>Test</div>]]></text></action></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>    
</layout>
```

ctabuttons.phtml

```
<?php
/**
*/
Mage::log(get_class($this));
echo 'this is my test';
```

CtaButtons.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName_CtaAttributes_Block_CtaButtons extends Mage_Core_Block_Template  {
    echo 'test';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - it is in two parts.

1. I did not define an frontend->update path for my layout update. I inserted this after `</global>`

   ```
     <frontend>
       <layout>
           <updates>
               <ctaattributes>
                   <file>ctaattributes.xml</file>
               </ctaattributes>
           </updates>
       </layout>  
   </frontend>
   ```

Had I used local.xml, I dont believe this would have been required, but in my testing I thought I would change the file name to keep it separate.

2. **You cannot use camel case in the Block Class Name**

Originaly my class was `CompanyName_CtaAttributes_Block_CtaButtons` - with a corresponding file called `CtaButtons.php`.
Changing the name to `CompanyName_CtaAttributes_Block_Ctabuttons` and `Ctabuttons.php` has resolved the issue.

I don't know if it is the Class file in Block/Blockname.php or the layout xml file that has a problem.

I have tested this with CamelCase in the company name and module with no impact, it seems to be restricted to the Blockname class and file.

Answer (score 0):

- The /Blocks/CtaButtons.xml in you file structure should be an php
  file.
- I don't see the module file which should be in /app/etc/modules
- You should have module Versioning in the config.xml

Comment: Hi Bernhard - I have updated it on my question. It was an error in the question, the file is a .php file.  Also, I have not included the module file to keep the question shorter.  I have also removed the version from the question - it is there though.

Comment: Try with template hint extension to seek for the block. Is it there? Does the extension show at all on System>advanced? Does the xml, combinded with the phtml work at all? Try that within layout.xml for a test.... try to narrow down....

Comment: Thanks Bernhard.  Found the issue but installing a template hint extension will be useful down the line

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to define block type first

From

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <layout version="0.1.0">
     <catalog_product_view>    
         <reference name="content">

                 <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.addtocart" before="addtocart" template="ctaattributes/catalog/product/ctabuttons.phtml"/>
                 <action method="append">
                         <block>ctabuttons</block>
                 </action>
         </reference>

         <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
             <block type="core/text_list" name="core-text"><action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<div>Test</div>]]></text></action></block>
         </reference>
     </catalog_product_view>    
 </layout>
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>    
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.ctaattributes" before="addtocart" template="ctaattributes/catalog/product/ctabuttons.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>    
</layout>
```

Comment: I have updated the ctabuttons.xml in line with your resonse -         `<reference name="content">
  
    <block type="ctaattributes/ctaButtons" name="product.info.addtocart" before="addtocart" template="ctaattributes/catalog/product/ctabuttons.phtml"/>

                <action method="append">
                        <block>ctabuttons</block>
                </action>
        </reference>` - still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest patch your blocks should also be allowed in the System->Permission->block